# MS Access VBA Open a Text file and write to a specific line without overwriting the file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a text file that I would like to add a header and a footer to.  I don't want to overwrite the first or last lines, rather I'd like to add a new first line and append a line to the end of the file.

The below Function works for appending to the bottom of the file but I'd like to be able to control where the line is inserted.  Thank you!

```
Function WriteToText(sFile As String, sText As String)

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim iFileNumber           As Integer

    iFileNumber = FreeFile                   ' Get unused file number
    Open sFile For Append As #iFileNumber    ' Connect to the file
    Print #iFileNumber, sText                ' Append our string
    Close #iFileNumber                       ' Close the file   Exit_Err_Handler:
    Exit Function   Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: Txt_Append" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    GoTo Exit_Err_Handler End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do for a task like this:

1. Read the whole file into a string (`Open For Input`)
2. Add the data you want: `S = "header line" & vbCrLf & S & vbCrLf & "footer line"`
3. Write the whole string to the file, overwriting it (`Open For Output`)

Comment: Thank you for your response, what is the most efficient way to open for input and output?  I'm very new to reading and writing to .txt files.  I'm not even exactly sure how my code above works as I got most of it from a different forum

Comment: This has examples for everything you need: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-text-files